# Sending request with angular - empty elements in request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sending POST request with angular with submitted form.
I have optionals input fields and when I type something there and delete it then in my request I have this field containing "".
Is that how it should be?

Thats how my form look:

```
<label class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 my-label"  for="contactFirstName">Imię</label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactFirstName" name="contactFirstName"
               placeholder="Imię"
               ng-model="loan.newLoan.contactPerson.firstName" >
      </div>
```

And thats how I'm sending the request:

```
function create() {
return RequestFactory.save({id1:'loans', id2:'create'},vm.newLoan,
    function () {
      MessageFactory.setSuccess({show:true, msg:'success'});
      $state.reload('loan.new');
    }, function(response){
      vm.isError = true;
      ErrorFactory.errorHandler(vm.errorMessages, response);
    });
}
```

And when sending, in my request json with this field looks like this:

```
 {"firstName":""}
```

Is that ok? Or there should't be this field in the request if its empty?
What should I do with this?

Comment: Hello! Please accept my answer if it solves your problem. :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170863)

Comment: Yes it solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that ok?

Yes or not, depends of what your backend service is expecting.

You can remove the empty fields in Angular by doing something like

```
function create() {
    var data = {};

    if (vm.newLoan.contactPerson.firstName) {
        data.firstName = vm.newLoan.contactPerson.firstName;
    }

    RequestFactory.save({ id1: 'loans', id2: 'create' }, data, ...);
}
```

And you should do a supplementary check in your backend service to remove the empty fields if you don't want to save it. Never trust the data sent from a client, even if you validate the data in JavaScript. Always do an extra check in the server code.

Answer (score 1):

Hence your html input field is not required, it is perfectly fine.Hope your backed service also an optional field.If it's a required field then you have to check as shown below when you press the `Save` button.

This is just an example:

***Html***

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary blue" ng-
click="vm.save(yourFormName.$valid)"> Save</button>
```

***JS***

```
    //to save 
    vm.save = function (isValid) {
        if (isValid) {
            //fires save method here
        }
    };
```